# 5.1 not running over HDMI

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I have the following setup:
PC (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Nvidia GeForce 1050Ti, Nvidia X server installed) connected over HDMI to Samsung Q85 TV, which is connected over HDMI ARCH, to a 5.2 (Dolby Atmos Onkyo system).

I tested PulseAudio and I only get sounds from the left/right speaker, but non of the rest.

At first, I thought it could be due to one of the HDMI cables, and I rotated a bit with a 3rd (latest gen) HDMI, but the truth is I have no clue how to troubleshoot the rest. Unfortunately, the Samsung doesn't have the same testing util as in PulseAudio.

Any hints/help would be appreciated!

P.S. Before coming here, I've googled a bit ... but nothing that matches my setup.

Thanks in advance!